# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" getting this error while using ticker for countdown

Tags: java, android-studio

I want a int value from edit text  so I can use it on  `.setCounterInSeconds(long)` but I'm getting this error.   My code is:

```
 entertime = findViewById(R.id.Txt_time);
 int som = Integer.parseInt(entertime.getText().toString());




    circularViewWithTimer = findViewById(R.id.circular_view);
    CircularView.OptionsBuilder builderWithTimer =
            new CircularView.OptionsBuilder()
                    .shouldDisplayText(true)
                    .setCounterInSeconds(som)
```

I only want to get the time entered by the user so it start by user entered time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you haven't written anything in `Edittext`. Before parsing value from `Edittext` you should check if it is null or empty:

```
if(enterTime.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(this,"You should enter number",Toast.LENGTG_SHORT).show()
}else{
    doYourJob()
}
```